# Swift Delete not working/showing up in table view

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

So I am building an app using a table view. The problem is that the swipe to delete is not showing up in the simulator. When ever I try to swipe it to the left, nothing pops up. Here is the code for the main view controller. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate {

var tableView : UITableView?

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
// Table View where the goals are displayed



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
navigationItem.title =  "Goal List"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    table.reloadData()



}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return goalMgr.goals.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //Assinging the contents of our goal array into rows
    cell.textLabel?.text = goalMgr.goals[indexPath.row].goal
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = goalMgr.goals[indexPath.row].time
    return cell


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var detail:SecondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as SecondVC

    detail.cellGoal = goalMgr.goals[indexPath.row].goal
    detail.cellTime = goalMgr.goals[indexPath.row].time

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail, animated: true)

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!){

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

        goalMgr.removeGoal(indexPath.row)
        table.reloadData()

        }

  }

}
```

Here is the file in which the removeGoal function is created

```
import UIKit

var goalMgr:GoalManager = GoalManager()

struct Goal{
var goal: String = "Goal"
var time: String = "Time"
 }

class GoalManager: NSObject {

var goals = [Goal]()
var persistentHelper: PersistentHelper = PersistentHelper()

override init(){

    var tempGoals:NSArray = persistentHelper.list("Goal")
    for res:AnyObject in tempGoals{
        goals.append(Goal(goal:res.valueForKey("goal")as String,time:res.valueForKey("time") as String))
    }

}

func addGoal(goal:String, time: String){

    var dicGoal: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
    dicGoal["goal"] = goal
    dicGoal["time"] = time

    if(persistentHelper.save("Goal", parameters: dicGoal)){
        goals.append(Goal(goal: goal, time: time))
    }
}


func removeGoal(index:Int){

    var value:String = goals[index].goal

    if(persistentHelper.remove("Goal", key: "goal", value: value)){
        goals.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}    

  }
```

Comment: I am also using core data.

Comment: Is your tableView datasource and delegate set to self?

Comment: The datasource and delegate methods won't do anything if your tableView isn't set to communicate with them. Either in Interface Builder you can set this or programatically in your viewDidLoad method you can add `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.datasource = self`

Comment: Thanks for advice but it's still not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` method seems off. It looks like you've pasted the method below inside of it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

You've already defined the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath` method above the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` method.

**Update**

You say that when you swipe, the delete button isn't shown. But is the content of the cell swiped to the left? If so, try this:

1. Rotate your device in the simulator (to the left or right)
2. Make sure you can see both sides of the row (the separator should be fully visible within the view)
3. Now, swipe

Everything seems fine in your code, so I'm guessing that the delete button is there, but it is simply out of view in portrait mode. It should be visible in landscape though, that's why I'm suggesting the above steps.

If you see the delete button in landscape mode, you need to adjust your alignment of your UITableView with auto layout.

Comment: That is true, thanks for the catch, I deleted the extra method. But its still not working

Comment: This worked! Hahaha what a newbie error of me to do, I have been trying to find a solution for hours. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To get swipe to work you have to implement `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`

In this function you return the editing style your row supports. Only if this is implemented does swipe to delete work. So in here return `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete`.

If you want to change the text label in the red box which shows on swipe, implement `tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`

`tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` is only there to let you veto which rows support being edited.

Comment: So I should add this line of code to the vc file?                                                 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    
    }

Comment: Yes. That looks right. Swipe activation is driven off this being implemented by the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that "User Interaction Enabled" is checked for the Table View Cell in the Attributes Inspector.  It is checked by default, but if you have unchecked it at some point the swipe to delete function will not work.